# Could not execute method of Activity

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

Well I have set of buttons and their `onClick` property is "click" like this `android:onClick="click"`. I am running this in android 2.2

Here's the click function in the main activity. This function is outside the `onCreate` method as expected.

```
public void click(View v)
{
    String s = et2.getText().toString();

    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.b0 :      
            if(s.length() == 1 && s.charAt(0) == '0')
            {  
                et2.setText("0");
                et1.setText("0");
            }
            else
            {
                s = s + "0";
                call(s);
            }
        break;
        //Other cases
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I click any button, the app stops working (Force Close).

Here's the Log:

> 03-30 22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-30 22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity 03-30 22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):  at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044) 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   03-30 22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-30
>   22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)  03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   ... 11 more 03-30 22:23:20.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1240): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-30 22:23:20.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):   at
>   yadav.sanjay.calculator.CalculatorActivity.click(CalculatorActivity.java:63)

Comment: `click()` should be `onClick()`.

Comment: what is on line 63 of your CalculatorActivity.java ?

Comment: Line 63 : `String s=et2.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException,
Usually, this means your staff is not initialized yet. 
Check the code around Line 63.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `et2` is inicialized. If you are using `findViewById()` please check if you do that after the `setContent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code on line 63 into two separate lines, like this.

```
String s; //you should probably change s to something less common like calS or the like
s = et2.getText().toString();
```

I think another thing that could be the problem is that et2 was never initialized. Make sure you have initialized et2.